# How to return Json from 2.0 Web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to create json webservice in net 2.0 and I have to download json string from [Football-api](http://football-api.com/api/?Action=competitions&APIKey=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D&comp_id=%5BCOMPETITION_ID%5D) and I want to return that json to clients as it is. This api has some interval limitations (80 requests per hour) thats why i cant directly download json to my clients. How to create this webservice in asp.net 2.0 in c#? And how to limit these requests in web service?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70(v=vs.80).aspx. Your question is too broad. A good answer would be far too long and detailed and unbalanced relative to your question.

Comment: Besides, if you are writing a new web service you should use ASP.NET Web API 2, http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-web-api

Comment: I want a simple method because i am new to this, i just have to Download json from one url and forward it to other clients(in this case its mobile users).